# how to upload image server side in ionic 2 / 3

Tags: ios, node.js, ionic-framework, server, ionic2

I'm building an app with Ionic 2. I need to take a photo from gallery or camera and upload this picture to my server.
I have this code that opens the Gallery and takes a picture.

```
accessGallery() {
    this.camera.getPicture({
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    }).then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.uploadFile();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err); 
    });
  }
```

upload image to server side

```
uploadFile() {

      let body = new FormData();
      body.append('images', this.base64Image);
      let headers = new Headers({
        'token': this.token,
        'sid': this.sid,
        'user': this.user,
        'to': this.to,
        'node': this.node,
        'type':'image' 

      });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      console.log("header ----" +JSON.stringify(headers));
      console.log("images data body----" +JSON.stringify(body));

      this.http.post(this.apiurl,body,options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data);
              },
              err => {
                console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
              }
          );
    }
```

ERROR :- Field value too long

Comment: What is your backend?

Comment: @David R node.js

Comment: What I meant to ask was, the node rest url to which you are trying post your image points to which database?

Comment: @David R  database myql

Answer (score 0):

As the error description clearly suggests, it seems you are trying to pass a value to one of your mysql table's field which is smaller than the value you are trying to pass.

Try outputting your `options` array and cross check each of its value against the respective db field and if you find any discrepancy modify the respective field length accordingly.

Hope this helps!